# How to set the center of the actor to be the same as the center of mass of the body

Tags: libgdx, render, center, box2d

Here is a star-shaped body created with Physics Body Editor with the center of mass in the middle:

```
val bodyEditorLoader by lazy { BodyEditorLoader(Gdx.files.internal("phisics/GameBox2D.json")) }
val starBody = createStar()

private fun createStar(): Body {
    val bodyDef = BodyDef().apply {
        type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody
        position.set(
            mainLayoutUtil.getSizeW(700f),
            mainLayoutUtil.getSizeH(350f),
        )
    }
    val body = WorldUtil.world.createBody(bodyDef)

    val fixtureDef = FixtureDef().apply {
        restitution = 0.7f
        density = 1f
    }

    bodyEditorLoader.attachFixture(body, "Star", fixtureDef, 10f)

    return body



"rigidBodies": [
{
  "name": "Star",
  "imagePath": "../star.png",
  "origin": {
    "x": 0.5,
    "y": 0.5,
  },
}
...
]
```

The image that needs to display the body data:

```
private val starImage = Image(SpriteManager.GameRegion.STAR.region)
```

Image rendering method according to body data:

```
override fun render(delta: Float) {
    super.render(delta)
    WorldUtil.update(delta)
    WorldUtil.debug(viewport.camera.combined)

    renderStar()
}

private fun renderStar() {
    starImage.apply {

        x = starBody.???
        y = starBody.???
        setOrigin(starBody.???)

        rotation = Math.toDegrees(starBody.???).toFloat()
    }
}
```

What body data should I use to correctly render the image according to the body data?

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable into which the Vector2 will be written:

```
var starCenter = Vector2()
```

In the body creation method, write the center of mass to the already created variable:

```
private fun createStar(): Body {
   val center = bodyEditorLoader.getOrigin("Star", 10F)
   starCenter = center

   return body
}
```

Replace the image data with the following body data to render the image correctly:

```
private fun renderStar() {
    starImage.apply {

        x = starBody.position.x - starCenter.x
        y = starBody.position.y - starCenter.y
        setOrigin(starCenter.x, starCenter.y)

        rotation = Math.toDegrees(starBody.angle.toDouble()).toFloat()
    }
}
```